# Assigning default values to shell variables with a single command in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a whole bunch of tests on variables in a bash (3.00) shell script where if the variable is not set, then it assigns a default, e.g.:

```
if [ -z "${VARIABLE}" ]; then 
    FOO='default'
else 
    FOO=${VARIABLE}
fi
```

I seem to recall there's some syntax to doing this in one line, something resembling a ternary operator, e.g.:

```
FOO=${ ${VARIABLE} : 'default' }
```

(though I know that won't work...)

Am I crazy, or does something like that exist?

Comment: Shell Parameter Expansion section of the bash shell reference is a good starting places: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions.

Comment: Gnu.org documentation for [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (hint: there's a lot of other cool stuff you can do!)

Answer (score 2407, accepted):

Very close to what you posted, actually. You can use something called [Bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to accomplish this.

To get the assigned value, or `default` if it's missing:

```
FOO="${VARIABLE:-default}"  # FOO will be assigned 'default' value if VARIABLE not set or null.
# The value of VARIABLE remains untouched.
```

To do the same, as well as assign `default` to `VARIABLE`:

```
FOO="${VARIABLE:=default}"  # If VARIABLE not set or null, set it's value to 'default'. 
# Then that value will be assigned to FOO
```

Comment: If I wanted to find this in the documentation, what would a google for?  Googling with special characters like ${:-} isn't very easy.

Comment: In response to solarmist: "bash variable assignment default" let me to this page, and searching bash's manual page with 'variable ass' got me to the right section after ~five 'next'

Comment: Note that it's [*not* bash-specific](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) and will work with the whole shell-family. It's safe for generic-scripts.

Comment: @solarmist The key word is "bash parameter expansion", if you want to find more about it and its companions.

Comment: What is the difference between :- and := ?

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande I confirm: I tryed in a common profile it is sourced both by bash and zsh I use in my git versioned [home](https://github.com/fibo/home) and it works well on both.

Comment: @Andrew the := is very clear and intuitive among many other [shell substitutions statements](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Comment: subjectAltName=${1:-${SUBJECT_ALT_NAME:-$defaultSubjectAltName}};  ... is the syntax for 3 alternatives ... here the first default is the first param passed to  the script, else an env var is used else a script var is used

Comment: Here's a more in-depth explanation on the topic http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122848/2407

Comment: This page has a nice cheat sheet explaining all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16753536/5359531

Comment: Is it possible to use shell special variables like `${@:-default}` Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @JoshuaOlson: example how to google: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=difference+%24%7Bparameter%3A%3Dword%7D+and+%24%7Bparameter%3A-word%7D

Comment: Worth clarifying that "null" in bash documentation simply means empty string.  (quite confusing jargon to people coming from other languages, as it sounds like NULL or nil  singleton values that are distinct from strings; but no, in bash it refers to empty string which is a regular value, whereas variable "not set" at all is the distinct state)

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande So the name "Bash parameter expansion" is misleading and the whole thing is POSIX compliant.

Comment: nested fallbacks are also possible: `echo "${FOO:-${BAR:-fallback value}}"`

Answer (score 616):

For command line arguments:

```
VARIABLE="${1:-$DEFAULTVALUE}"
```

which assigns to `VARIABLE` the value of the 1st argument passed to the script or the value of `DEFAULTVALUE` if no such argument was passed. Quoting prevents globbing and word splitting.

Comment: Technically you don't need the quotes in this instance, because the RHS value in a variable assignment is already not subject to the globbing or word splitting that the quotes are intended to prevent; only tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal. Same applies to the stuff between the :- and the closing brace. That said, using quotes is pretty harmless.

Answer (score 439):

If the variable is same, then

```
: "${VARIABLE:=DEFAULT_VALUE}"
```

assigns `DEFAULT_VALUE` to `VARIABLE` if not defined.

- The [colon builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) (`:`) ensures the variable result is not executed
- The double quotes (`"`) prevent globbing and word splitting.

Also see Section 3.5.3, [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), in the Bash manual.

Comment: This tricky trick wasn't obvious to me, using the :  no-effect builtin to eat the expansion of the ${..} BUT leaving VARIABLE set. Until now I was doing this: VARIABLE="${VARIABLE:-DEFAULT_VALUE}" and feeling dorky for using VARIABLE twice.

Comment: It turns out THIS DOES NOT ALWAYS WORK FOR BASH-BUILTIN VARIABLES. It's very very weird. Currently those known to me are `HISTTIMEFORMAT`

Comment: how would I set multiple default values? I tried ": ${VARIABLE:=DEFAULT_VALUE} : ${VARIABLE2:=DEFAULT_VALUE2}" but that doesnt seem to work...

Comment: @Hans: The colon is the command (which does nothing) and thus is needed only once. E.g. `: ${FOO:=DEFAULT1} ${BAR:=DEFAULT2}`

Comment: Any chance to use something like this with `export`? I want to make this variable available to the scripts called from the current script.

Comment: @SergeRogatch Just call `export VARIABLE` after you set it.

Comment: Or you can execute `set -a`, if you need to export all the variables in the script.

Comment: The good part is, this is POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 133):

To answer your question and on all variable substitutions

```
echo "${var}"
echo "Substitute the value of var."
    

echo "${var:-word}"
echo "If var is null or unset, word is substituted for var. The value of var does not change."
    

echo "${var:=word}"
echo "If var is null or unset, var is set to the value of word."
    

echo "${var:?message}"
echo "If var is null or unset, message is printed to standard error. This checks that variables are set correctly."
    

echo "${var:+word}"
echo "If var is set, word is substituted for var. The value of var does not change."
```

You can escape the whole expression by putting a \ between the dollar sign and the rest of the expression.

```
echo "$\{var}"
```

Comment: There's also `{var-default}` where `default` will be used only when `var` is undefined. If `var` is defined but null, `default` won't be used.

Comment: Why is there a a backslash in each line? Other answers don't have it.

Comment: The `"${var:?message}"` can be super-helpful later on when you're stuck with only the output as log for, let's say, why some CI script failed for example:
Instead of `MyCmd --key ${API_KEY}` erroring with (let's pretend): "MyCmd [ERROR] argument required", 
if you instead just do `MyCmd --key ${API_KEY:?}`, everyone can see an understandable error: `sh: API_KEY: parameter not set` and if `set -e`, the script will exit with error immediately 

Comment: `echo "$\{var}"` produces `$\{var}`, maybe you want `echo "\${var}"` which produces `${var}`.

Answer (score 65):

Even you can use like default value the value of another variable

having a file `defvalue.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
variable1=$1
variable2=${2:-$variable1}

echo $variable1
echo $variable2
```

run `./defvalue.sh first-value second-value` output

```
first-value
second-value
```

and run `./defvalue.sh first-value` output

```
first-value
first-value
```

Answer (score 44):

FWIW, you can provide an error message like so:

```
USERNAME=${1:?"Specify a username"}
```

This displays a message like this and exits with code 1:

```
./myscript.sh
./myscript.sh: line 2: 1: Specify a username
```

A more complete example of everything:

```
#!/bin/bash
ACTION=${1:?"Specify 'action' as argv[1]"}
DIRNAME=${2:-$PWD}
OUTPUT_DIR=${3:-${HOMEDIR:-"/tmp"}}

echo "$ACTION"
echo "$DIRNAME"
echo "$OUTPUT_DIR"
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh foo
foo
/path/to/pwd
/tmp

$ export HOMEDIR=/home/myuser
$ ./script.sh foo
foo
/path/to/pwd
/home/myuser
```

- `$ACTION` takes the value of the first argument, and exits if empty
- `$DIRNAME` is the 2nd argument, and defaults to the current directory
- `$OUTPUT_DIR` is the 3rd argument, or `$HOMEDIR` (if defined), else, `/tmp`. This works on OS X, but I'm not positive that it's portable.

Comment: It's no wonder these timesaver bash functions are unknown by a lot of people. How can you search for them? bash macros, bash functions, bash builtins nothing gets you there.

Answer (score 42):

see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) under 3.5.3(shell parameter expansion)

so in your case

```
${VARIABLE:-default}
```

Answer (score 34):

It is possible to chain default values like so:

```bash
DOCKER_LABEL=${GIT_TAG:-${GIT_COMMIT_AND_DATE:-latest}}
```

i.e. if `$GIT_TAG` doesnt exist, take `$GIT_COMMIT_AND_DATE` - if this doesnt exist, take `"latest"`

Comment: Very nice and useful 

Answer (score 24):

Then there's the way of expressing your 'if' construct more tersely:

```
FOO='default'
[ -n "${VARIABLE}" ] && FOO=${VARIABLE}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example

```
#!/bin/bash

default='default_value'
value=${1:-$default}

echo "value: [$value]"
```

save this as script.sh and make it executable.
run it without params

```
./script.sh
> value: [default_value]
```

run it with param

```
./script.sh my_value
> value: [my_value]
```

Answer (score 7):

Parameter Substitution, is NOT always the answer
`${parameter:-default}`

```bash
foo="$1"

o="${foo:-def}" # $foo, or def if unset (or null)
o="${foo:+def}" # def if $foo is set (and not null)
: "${foo:=def}" # Set $foo to def if unset (or null)
: "${foo:?msg}" # Show error message and exit if $foo is unset (or null)
```

###### While the default value (right side) can be an expression

###### The parameter (left side) **can NOT be an expression**

So if you want to assign based on an expression;
You'll end up doing some form of bellow

---

***For example***

###### Set `o` to `UPPER` if `x` is bigger than `50` or `LOWER` if it's not

```bash
# function get_o { ... }
echo "$(get_o 33)"; # LOWER
echo "$(get_o 77)"; # UPPER
```

---

### Set in Integer arithmetic condition

```bash
(( x > 50 )) && o="UPPER" || o="LOWER"
# or ..
[[ $x -ge 50 ]] && o="UPPER" || o="LOWER"
```

---

### Set with Command substitution

```bash
o="$( (( x > 50 )) && echo "UPPER" || echo "LOWER" )"
```

---

### Set default later with parameter substitution

```bash
(( x > 50 )) && o="UPPER"
: "${o:=LOWER}"
```

---

### Set default first then update

```bash
o="LOWER"
(( x > 50 )) && o="UPPER"
```

*Or with full if syntax ...*

Answer (score 5):

If you want 1 liner for your if-then-else, then we can consider rewriting:

```bash
if [ -z "${VARIABLE}" ]; then 
    FOO='default'
else 
    FOO=${VARIABLE}
fi
```

with semicolons:

```bash
if [ -z ${VARIABLE} ]; then FOO=`default`; else FOO=${VARIABLE}; fi
```

Alternatively, you can drop the `if-then-else-fi` keywords if you use boolean operators such as:

```bash
[ -z "${VARIABLE}" ] && FOO='default' || FOO=${VARIABLE}
```

Generalizing, the boolean operator pattern is:

```bash
conditional && then_command || else_command
```

Comment: I like the `[ -z "${VARIABLE}" ] && FOO='default'` variant. Useful when I want to prompt the user for input but provide a default value. Cheers :)