# How to write a bash script that takes optional input arguments?

Tags: bash, arguments, parameter-passing

I want my script to be able to take an optional input,

e.g. currently my script is

```
#!/bin/bash
somecommand foo
```

but I would like it to say:

```
#!/bin/bash
somecommand  [ if $1 exists, $1, else, foo ]
```

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013547/assigning-default-values-to-shell-variables-with-a-single-command-in-bash

Comment: I want to say that the this subject is not about the optional argument but a positional argument with default value. This terminology gives much confusion. "Optional argument" means it would be ok whether those arguments exist in the command line or not.

Answer (score 1085, accepted):

You could use the default-value syntax:

```
somecommand ${1:-foo}
```

The above will, as described in [Bash Reference Manual - 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) [emphasis mine]:

> If parameter is unset *or null*, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

If you only want to substitute a default value if the parameter is unset (but not if it's null, e.g. not if it's an empty string), use this syntax instead:

```
somecommand ${1-foo}
```

Again from [Bash Reference Manual - 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests for both parameter’s existence and that its value is not null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.

Comment: Please note the semantic difference between the above command, "return `foo` if `$1` is unset *or an empty string*", and `${1-foo}`, "return `foo` if `$1` is unset".

Comment: Can you explain why this works? Specially, what's the function/purpose of the ':' and '-'?

Comment: @jwein001: In the answer submitted above, a substitution operator is used to return a default value if the variable is undefined.  Specifically, the logic is "If $1 exists and isn't null, return its value; otherwise, return foo."  The colon is optional. If it's omitted, change "exists and isn't null" to only "exists."  The minus sign specifies to return foo without setting $1 equal to 'foo'.  Substitution operators are a subclass of expansion operators. See section 6.1.2.1 of Robbins and Beebe's *Classic Shell Scripting* [O'Reilly] (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005955.do)

Comment: @Jubbles or if you don't want to buy an entire book for a simple reference... http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: This answer would be even better if it showed how to make the default be the result of running a command, as @hagen does (though that answer is inelegant).

Comment: If the subcommand possible takes multiple paramters, then:    `somecommand ${@-foo}`

Comment: I am frustrated why this is optional argument. If you use $1 for a variable, it is positional argument not optional argument. If a command can receive an optional argument of -a -b -c then it should work with "command -a 10", "command -b ten",  "command -c abc" and "command -a 7 -c aaa". If it works always with three arguments such as "command 10 ten abc", it is not a optional argument.

Comment: @OhadSchneider, please reconsider linking to the ABS -- it's a source of enough bad-practice examples that [entire alternative reference sources](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) have been written to replace it after the #bash IRC support channel got fed up with trying to get people to unlearn bad habits they picked up there. (https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe is another good reference on the specific topic at hand; the Wooledge wiki also has parameter expansion coverage in [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) and [#73](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073))

Comment: Is it possible to "return `foo` if `$1` is set"?

Answer (score 550):

You can set a default value for a variable like so:

#### somecommand.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ARG1=${1:-foo}
ARG2=${2:-'bar is'}
ARG3=${3:-1}
ARG4=${4:-$(date)}

echo "$ARG1"
echo "$ARG2"
echo "$ARG3"
echo "$ARG4"
```

Here are some examples of how this works:

```
$ ./somecommand.sh
foo
bar is
1
Thu 19 May 2022 06:58:52 ADT

$ ./somecommand.sh ez
ez
bar is
1
Thu 19 May 2022 06:58:52 ADT

$ ./somecommand.sh able was i
able
was
i
Thu 19 May 2022 06:58:52 ADT

$ ./somecommand.sh "able was i"
able was i
bar is
1
Thu 19 May 2022 06:58:52 ADT

$ ./somecommand.sh "able was i" super
able was i
super
1
Thu 19 May 2022 06:58:52 ADT

$ ./somecommand.sh "" "super duper"
foo
super duper
1
Thu 19 May 2022 06:58:52 ADT

$ ./somecommand.sh "" "super duper" hi you
foo
super duper
hi
you
```

Comment: Ah, ok. The `-` confused me (is it negated?).

Comment: Nope - that's just a weird way bash has of doing the assignment. I'll add some more examples to clarify this a bit... thanks!

Comment: It looks this is the limit of bash argument. Using python terminology, this is not optional, it is positional. It is just a positional argument with default values. Is there no really optional argument in bash?

Comment: you may be able to use getopts to get what you want - Here's 2 stackoverflow answers that go into greater detail: [dfeault values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22058316/26510) and [inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16655341/26510)

Comment: Note also, that to confuse even more (with JSON/python dicts) no space is permitted anywhere, e.g. after the colon and/or after/before the dash... where is the principle of least astonishment here?:)

Comment: good point @mirekphd - I added an example showing how to put spaces in a default value. You can use single quotes if you want a literal value, or double quotes if you want variables to be interpolated

Answer (score 68):

```
if [ ! -z $1 ] 
then 
    : # $1 was given
else
    : # $1 was not given
fi
```

Comment: Technically, if you pass in an empty string '' that might count as a parameter, but your check will miss it. In that case $# would say how many parameters were given

Comment: `-n` is the same as `! -z`.

Comment: I get different results using `-n` and `! -z` so I would say that is not the case here.

Comment: because you failed to quote the variable, `[ -n $1 ]` *will always be true*. If you use bash, `[[ -n $1 ]]` will behave as you expect, otherwise you must quote `[ -n "$1" ]`

Comment: For ones like me: forget the ":" in the code, it's not required, replace it with your real commands!

Answer (score 35):

You can check the number of arguments with `$#`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ge 1 ]
then
    $1
else
    foo
fi
```

Answer (score 13):

please don't forget, if its variable $1 .. $n 
you need write to a regular variable to use the substitution

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$1
echo  ${NOW:-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")}
```

Comment: Brad's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33419280/603516) above proves that argument variables can also be substituted without intermediate vars.

Comment: +1 for noting the way to use a command like date as the default instead of a fixed value. This is also possible: `DAY=${1:-$(date +%F -d "yesterday")}`

Answer (score 10):

This allows default value for optional 1st arg, and preserves multiple args.

```
 > cat mosh.sh
   set -- ${1:-xyz} ${@:2:$#} ; echo $*    
 > mosh.sh
   xyz
 > mosh.sh  1 2 3
   1 2 3
```

Answer (score 6):

For optional *multiple* arguments, by analogy with the `ls` command which can take one or more files or by default lists everything in the current directory:

```
if [ $# -ge 1 ]
then
    files="$@"
else
    files=*
fi
for f in $files
do
    echo "found $f"
done
```

Does not work correctly for files with spaces in the path, alas. Have not figured out how to make that work yet.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to use variable substitution to substitute a fixed value or a command (like `date`) for an argument. The answers so far have focused on fixed values, but this is what I used to make date an optional argument:

```
~$ sh co.sh
2017-01-05

~$ sh co.sh 2017-01-04
2017-01-04

~$ cat co.sh

DAY=${1:-$(date +%F -d "yesterday")}
echo $DAY
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
while getopts a: flag
do
    case "$flag" in
        a) arg1=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

echo "Print optional argument: $arg1"

if [[ -z "$arg1" ]]; then
    ARG=DEFAULT_VAL
else
    ARG=$arg1
fi  

#Run using below command (eg: file name : runscript.sh)
bash runscript.sh -a argument_val &
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use ${1: } you can catch the **first parameter**(1) passed to your function or(:) you can catch a **blank space** like a default value.

For example. To be able to use Laravel artisan, I put this into my .bash_aliases file:

```
artisan() {
    docker exec -it **container_name** php artisan ${1: } ${2: } ${3: } ${4: } ${5: } ${6: } ${7: }
}
```

and now, I can just type in command line:

- artisan -- and all parameters(${1: } ${2: } ${3: } ${4: } ${5: } ${6: } ${7: }) will be just blank spaces
- artisan cache:clear -- and the first parameter ( **${1: }** ) will be cache:clear and all the others will be just blank spaces

So, in this case I can pass 7 parameters optionally.

I hope it can help someone.