# bash getopts multiple arguments or default value

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, getopts

So I have a question about get opts in bash.  I want to get the value of the arguments if they are present but if they are not present to use a default value.  So the script should take a directory and an integer but if they aren't specified then $PWD and 3 should be default values.  Here is what

```
while getopts "hd:l:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        d ) directory=$OPTARG;;
        l ) depth=$OPTARG;;
        h ) usage
        exit 0;;
        \? ) usage
        exit 1;;
    esac
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can just provide default value before `while` loop:

```
directory=mydir
depth=123
while getopts "hd:l:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        d ) directory=$OPTARG;;
        l ) depth=$OPTARG;;
        h ) usage
        exit 0;;
        *) usage
        exit 1;;
    esac
done
echo "<$directory> <$depth>"
```

Comment: So I did that (makes total sense) but the directory and depth never change

Comment: So if the argument exists then I want to change the variable directory to whatever is passed into option -d but if it is not present then just leave it at the current working directory.

Comment: you can just do `-d ) cd "$OPTARG";;` for that

Comment: is there a way to check if its valid?

Comment: yes sure you can do: `-d ) [[ -d "$OPTARG" ]] && cd "$OPTARG";;`

Comment: ok thanks a lot for helping me out but it still doesn't change directories

Comment: it does change but shell scripts are run in a sub shell so changed directory is not reflected in parent shell

Comment: also I need to humbly point that question was about setting default values which my answer provides. Would it not be better to ask a separate question about directory changing problem after accepting this answer.

Comment: I figured it all out.  Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

After your getopts, try this

if [ -z "$directory" ]; then directory="directory"; fi

-z means if the variable $directory is null or empty. Then if user doesnt enter an argument for -d, then the script will default to directory="/whatever/files/"

At least if I understand your question correctly, this should give you a default value for -d if a value is not entered.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.