# Angular: npm script with params

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, package.json, npm-scripts

I have few npm scripts in my package.json as:

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve-india-local": "ng serve --project pro-india -c local",
  "serve-india-stag": "ng serve --project pro-india -c stag",
  "serve-india-prod": "ng serve --project pro-india -c prod",
  ...
}
```

Similarly for brazil

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "serve-brazil-local": "ng serve --project pro-brazil -c local",
  "serve-brazil-stag": "ng serve --project pro-brazil -c stag",
  "serve-brazil-prod": "ng serve --project pro-brazil -c prod"
}
```

And similarly, I can have a few more scripts for different countries and configs.

I want to reduce this to a single script where I can take just 2 params:

- `countryName`
- `config`

So the final script should look something like this:

```json
"serve-india-prod": "ng serve --project pro-$countryName -c $config"
```

---

Can someone help me to achieve this ?

Comment: this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356509/6885735

Comment: On _*nix_ platforms npm uses `sh` as the default shell, therefore you can wrap your npm script in a shell function and reference the two arguments (i.e. `countryName` and `config`) using the `$1` and `$2`  positional parameter(s). However if your want a cross-platform solution (i.e. one that also works with the Windows `cmd` shell) then you'll need to utilize a _node.js_ helper script instead. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388921/pass-command-line-args-to-npm-scripts-in-package-json/51401577#answer-51401577.) for further understanding.

Comment: For instance; utilizing a _*nix_ shell function your npm-script  can be defined as: `"serve": "func() { ng serve --project \"pro-${1}\" -c \"${2}\"; }; func"`. Then you invoke the command e.g. `npm run serve brazil prod` or e.g. `npm run serve india local` etc...

Comment: You can also provide a [default-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332802/how-to-write-a-bash-script-that-takes-optional-input-arguments#answer-9333006) for  the `$1` and `$2` positional parameters. For instance if you change your npm-script to: `"serve": "func() { ng serve --project \"pro-${1:-india}\" -c \"${2:-prod}\"; }; func"`. Now if you invoke the npm script by running the command without any arguments e.g. `npm run serve` it will default to `pro-india` and `prod`. Yet when you run the command with arguments e.g. `npm run serve brazil prod` it will use  `pro-brazil` and `prod`.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily accomplish this with shell variables

in `package.json` under `scripts`, include your npm script
 for example

```
{ 
    "scripts":{
     "serve-prod": "ng serve --project pro-$countryName -c $config"
    }
}
```

and in cli run as
`countryName=india config=local npm run serve-prod`

this will not work well with cross platform, but you can use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) or [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var)