# Shell script to replace long predefined arguments

Tags: linux, shell

This is probably the worst question I've asked, I wasn't entirely sure how to formulate it and google results are best when the search is short and concise.

So, I keep finding myself constantly running a more or less identical list of commands in a Linux terminal. For example:

`./some_script -argument1 -argument2 -argument3 [varying list of parameters that differ in type]`

Now, the script and first 3 arguments are always the same. I was thinking if there is a way, such that a new script could be written, so that my entire input is much shorter. Like:

`./new_script [varying list of parameters that differ in type]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333006/4175515

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a perfect place for an [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

```sh
alias new_script='./some_script -argument1 -argument2 -argument3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `new_script` in some directory in your `PATH`, for example in `/usr/local/bin/`. I usually create `~/bin` directory and add it to `PATH`. Some people like to follow [XDG specifications](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html) and add `~/.local/bin` to `PATH`.

The file needs to have executable rights and following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
./some_script -argument1 -argument2 -argument3 "$@"
```