# .\create.sh: line 52: X: command not found

Tags: bash, shell

I have this `shell` script but I don't know why it doesn't work after passing parameters to it...

Here it is

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Check the argument type and change the directory depending on it.
# Open with code


create() {
    directory="E:/husseinabbas/programming/Code"
    use_directory=""
    project_name="$1"
    project_type="$2"
    project_mode="$3" || "new"
    repository_name="$4" || "$project_name"
    repository_type="$5" || false
    if [[ "$project_type" == "html" ]]
      then
        use_directory="${directory}/html_css/$project_name"
    elif [[ "$project_type" == "node" ]] 
      then 
        use_directory="{$directory}/node-projects/$project_name"
    elif [[ "$project_type" == "php" ]] 
      then 
        use_directory="F:/XAMPP/htdocs/$project_name"
    elif [[ "$project_type" == "python" ]] 
      then 
        use_directory="{$directory}/python-projects/$project_name"
    elif [[ "$project_type" == "flutter" ]] 
      then 
        use_directory="{$directory}/android/$project_name"
    elif [[ "$project_type" == "test" ]] 
      then 
        use_directory="C:/Users/H.Abbas/Desktop/$project_name"
    else 
        return
    fi
    # Activate the venv
    cd "E:/husseinabbas/programming/Code/python-projects/day_automator"
    source venv/Scripts/activate
    python day_automator.py "$project_name" "$project_type" "$project_mode" "$repository_name" "$repository_type"
    cd "$use_directory" || return
    echo "# $project_name" >> README.md
    git init
    git add README.md
    git commit -m "init"
    git branch -M main
    git remote add origin https://github.com/husseinYY/$repository_name.git
    git push -u origin main
    code .
    
}

"$@"
```

And I'm using this command to run it;

```
sh .\create.sh my_day python all my_day false
```

And it gives me this:-

```
.\create.sh: line 52: my_day: command not found
```

I have read other answers to this question but they weren't helpful

This paragraph is just here because Stackoverflow robot wants more details hehe

Comment: You normally run scripts in the same directory with ./ and not .\ Also, it is good practice to enclose your parameters in quotes.

Comment: `project_mode="$3" || "new"` is not how you supply default values in the shell; use `project_mode="${3:-new}"` instead (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332802/how-to-write-a-bash-script-that-takes-optional-input-arguments)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script you are not calling your function `create`, so nothing is done.

Also you are expanding `"$@"` at the end: this prints the shell arguments you passed
trying to execute them.
The error message comes from "Line 52" that is exactly where `$@` is.

In your command:

```sh
sh ./create.sh my_day python all my_day false
```

- `$0` is the path of the script `./create.sh`
- `$1` is `my_day`
- `$2` is `python`
- ...

`$@` expands from `$1` to the final argument, this is why you receive error on `my_day` that is in fact `$1`.

Prepend `create` to `"$@"` and should be ok.

Check also [What does $@ mean in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994295/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Maybe "Replace `"$@"` with `create "$@"` and should be ok"?

Comment: Yes, also. If you write only `create` it will take arguments from the main script so It will work. But I like your solution more

Comment: @piertoni Just using `create` will *not* pass on the arguments to the main script, it will run the `create` function with no arguments.