# Default variable in bash when using -u flag?

Tags: bash

It is not hard to set a default variable in bash. E.g: [How to write a bash script that takes optional input arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332802/how-to-write-a-bash-script-that-takes-optional-input-arguments)

But, these methods fail when using `set -euxo pipefail`. What methods are compatible with the `-u` flag?

Example:

```
set -euxo pipefail

foo=${2:test}
echo $foo
```

for Bash `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Please give an example. I just tried `echo "${1:-foo}"` and it worked fine. What version of Bash are you using? I think I read that this behaviour can vary across versions. I'm using 5.0.

Comment: @wjandrea example given

Comment: It has to be colon-hyphen `:-` or hyphen `-`. A colon by itself `:` selects a substring, e.g. with `set -- hello world; test=2`, the result would be `rld`.

Comment: BTW, `set -e` is generally regarded in the bash community as a bad idea. See [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) describing the pitfalls with `set -e`, and [BashFAQ #112](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112) describing best practices for working with `set -u`. I _strongly_ advise explicit error handling in place of `set -e`, and more weakly advise static checking ([shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/) is widely integrated into, or available via a plugin for, many editors now) in place of `set -u`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer to the linked duplicate works fine -- you're just misreading it.

It suggests:

```
somecommand ${1:-foo} # GOOD
```

...or...

```
somecommand ${1-foo} # GOOD
```

...not...

```
somecommand ${1:foo} # BAD
```