# OR two values in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a variable that may or may not be empty. If it's not empty, I want that value. If it is empty, I want the value of some other command. Example:

```
my_function ()
{
    name_override="$1"
    user_name=${name_override} || $(git config "user.name")
}
```

I'm not sure if the code above will work. But basically I want to run `git config` and store that result in `user_name` if the `name_override` variable is unset (and thus `$1` would not have been provided).

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning default values to shell variables with a single command in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013547/assigning-default-values-to-shell-variables-with-a-single-command-in-bash)

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks that does answer my question. I did search prior to posting but I did not find that.

Comment: No problem, glad your problem is solved either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bash` idiom for accomplishing this is

```
user_name=${1:-$(git config "user.name")}
```

where `:-` says to use the value of `$1` if it is set and non-null, else use the following string.