# How to set the default value of a variable as an array?

Tags: bash

I recently discovered that it is possible to have Bash set the a variable to a default value when that variable is not set (as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013547/assigning-default-values-to-shell-variables-with-a-single-command-in-bash)).

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work when the default value is an array. As an example consider,

```
default_value=(0 1 2 3 4)

my_variable=${my_variable:=("${default_value[@]}")}

echo ${my_variable[0]}
(0 a  2 3 4) #returns array :-(

echo ${my_variable[1])
#returns empty
```

Does anyone know how do this? Note that changing `:=` to `:-` does not help.

Another issue is that whatever solution we get should also work for when `my_variable` already set beforehand as well, so that

```
my_variable=("a" "b" "c")
default_value=(0 1 2 3 4)

my_variable=${my_variable:=("${default_value[@]}")}

echo ${my_variable[0]}
"a" 

echo ${my_variable[1]}
"b" 

echo ${my_variable[2]}
"c"
```

Comment: It's a bit odd to even want to use `:=` with an array variable, since the `:` part seems to presuppose that it's a string variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it array use:

```
unset my_variable default_value
default_value=("a b" 10)
my_variable=( "${my_variable[@]:-"${default_value[@]}"}" )

printf "%s\n" "${my_variable[@]}"
a b
10

printf "%s\n" "${default_value[@]}"
a b
10
```

#### [Online Demo](http://ideone.com/2znfya)

As per `man bash`:

```
${parameter:-word}
   Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
   Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman I guess you'd do this: `my_variable=( "${my_variable[@]:-"${default_value[@]}"}" )`

Comment: Or just write directly what you mean:
`((${#my_variable[@]})) || my_variable=('default')`