# Passing environment variables in npm-scripts

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, environment-variables

I have a package.json with following (simplified) content in the scripts key:

```
...
scripts: {
   "start": "NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:=production} node start-app.js",
   "poststart": "echo $NODE_ENV"
}
...
```

From the command line I can run:

```
npm start
```

This will run my start-app.js script and set the process.env.NODE_ENV  environment variable to "production". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013589/228450) for syntax explanation.

The poststart will automatically run after start as described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

However poststart will not "inherit" the NODE_ENV shell environment variable, so the echo command will not echo anything.

My producation code is a little more complex, but what I am trying to accomplish is passing down the NODE_ENV variable from the "starting point" to dependent scripts. Any suggestions/best practices on how to do that?

I dont want to hardcode the NODE_ENV in the poststart, because I might want to do:

```
NODE_ENV=development npm start
```

and I want everyting "down the chain" inherit the same environment.

Comment: From [what I see](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), _he package.json fields are tacked onto the npm_package_ prefix_, so you may want to say `npm_package_node_env`.

Comment: When running multiple commands you should `export` the variable. `export NODE_ENV=something`

Answer (score 27):

You have a few options:

- [better-npm-run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-run),which can define an `env` for each command separately
- Instead of a `poststart` script, you can concatenate commands for npm like so: `"start": "NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:=production} node start-app.js && echo $NODE_ENV"`
- Use a process manager in production like [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). pm2 lets you define environment specific json files with settings such as `NODE_ENV`. At our company, we successfully run all of our apps in different environments with pm2 (all the while having the same start command)

Comment: Is the NODE_ENV still avalilable when you echo? I experience that its gone, ref https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env#known-limitations

Comment: Correct, with `cross-env` this is not possible. The second example actually assigns an environment variable (not using cross-env).

Comment: @MarioTacke I just gave this a test and it **does not assign** a variable. If it is set previous to the `npm start` command, it works (inside a `start` script command).

Comment: @kaiser it depends on your environment. Can you outline what does and doesn't work in your case? The above is a `poststart` script. `cross-env` also had breaking changes recently.

Comment: I just tested this in a `node:8-alpine` Docker container, running Nodejs v8 and NPM v5 and the variables assigned in the container persist. Anyway, I believe we got one misunderstanding: You talk about assigning a variable, if **it is not yet assigned**, while I understood that it will _override_ previously set variables (`NODE_ENV`), right?

Comment: That is correct. It will override a previously set environment variable whether or not it has been set yet.

Answer (score 14):

this is how I did it, first you need to install two dev-dependencies

https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd
this load your env var from your file

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env
this use environment variable in script

example scripts:

```
"env-cmd ./.config/prod.env cross-env-shell \"docker volume create $DOCKER_VOLUME\""
```

this load $DOCKER_VOLUME env var from prod.env

update:
starting from env-cmd version 10, you need specify -f flag if you want to use a custom env file path

```
"env-cmd -f ./.config/prod.env cross-env-shell \"docker volume create $DOCKER_VOLUME\""
```

Comment: This almost worked for me, but I had to drop the quotes after cross-env-shell, like so: `"env-cmd -f ./.env cross-env-shell docker compose build app --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=$NPM_TOKEN"`

Comment: in `package.json`, `scripts` section: `"example": "env-cmd --use-shell \"echo test > \\$FILE_PATH\""`

Comment: If no redirect required than even simplier: `"example2": "env-cmd -x echo \\$FILE_PATH"`

Answer (score 0):

It refused to work on Windows regardless of suggestions across multiple threads. I tried `$var`, `${var}`, `%var%`, `${env:var}`.

Finally, I just wrote a short script

```
const envFilenameWithoutExtension = "mockup";
// Note that the path does not include the filename
const envFilePath = require('path').join(__dirname, "..");

// This plugin looks for env files named <.env.mode_name> . Note the leading dot
// My env file uses a interpolated variables, like ... api_url = "${url}", and dot-env didn't translate these,
// but custom-env which I was already using, does
require("custom-env").env(envFilenameWithoutExtension, envFilePath);

// Grouped together mostly for convenient logging
const basicObject = {
    modeFolder: process.env.BUILD_FOLDER,
    mode: process.env.REACT_APP_MODE,
    // I use this variable later, basicObject.url, to make sure the file was read.
    // You'll need to change it to something you use.
    url: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
    command: ""
};

basicObject.command = `cross-env NODE_ENV=${envFilenameWithoutExtension} ...the rest of your command`;

if (!basicObject.url) {
    console.log(process.env);
    throw "Couldn't find the env file."
} else {
    console.log("basic-config", basicObject)
}

require('child_process').exec(basicObject.command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    } else if (stderr) {
        console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -5):

If you have small use cased, use better-npm-run. For small cases, it works fine. Somehow if you have a lot of commands and it hard manage. Try, [batman-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/batman-cli). Work well and handle lot of environment-dependent issues

npm i -g [batman-cli](https://github.com/deepakshrma/batman-cli)