# Assign default value to variable if one not set, in Bash

Tags: bash

I know I can do:

```
echo ${var:-4}
```

to print `4` if `var` is null,

but how to assign `-n` in this case..?

`echo ${var:--n}` does not work.

although this does work..

```
echo ${var:---n}
```

but in that case it prints out `--n` and I need it to print `-n`.

Comment: `echo` is literally allowed to do **anything** when passed `-n` as an argument. See [the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html): *"If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined"*. When passed `-n`, or any content with literal backslashes, `echo` could turn a backflip or kill your cat and still be POSIX-compliant. Follow the advice in the APPLICATION USAGE section of the spec, and use `printf` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning default values to shell variables with a single command in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013547/assigning-default-values-to-shell-variables-with-a-single-command-in-bash)

Comment: @ElmarPeise, ...I'm not sure it is -- the immediate cause is certainly different, at least.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not in the default, but in `echo`: `-n` has a special meaning for it (check `help echo`). Use `printf` instead:

```
printf '%s\n' "${var:--n}"
```

Comment: Yes, I knew about `-n` in echo.. but it didn't occur to me at the moment.. Interestingly this happened as a side effect.. if I happened to try with `${var:--a}`, it would work ;)