# What does expression `${ID:-}` do in shell script?

Tags: shell

I encountered `${ID:-}` in a shell script, but I am not sure what does this expression exactly do.

After a bit of googling I found that `${var}` and `$var` are both the same. Such expression is useful when we want to expand expression like `${foo}bar`.

However I didn't find any source explaining expression like `${ID:-}`.

> I would like to know about expression `${ID:-}`

Comment: @TomFenech This is used to avoid fatal errors when you have called `set -u` before

Comment: @xhienne that's interesting, thanks. I think that if you made your comment into an answer, this could become a separate question regard the empty default expansion, which would be an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${variable:-default_value}` is used to return the default value, if the variable is not set.

Related: [Assigning default values to shell variables with a single command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013547/assigning-default-values-to-shell-variables-with-a-single-command-in-bash)

Comment: It's not _related_, it's the same!