# Docker is not getting Postgres environment variables

Tags: postgresql, docker

Docker is using the variables from my .env file and i keep getting the error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: role "eli" does not
>   exist

I would like for Postgres to get the variables from the environment set in `docker-compose.yml`

**.env**

```
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=elitest4
POSTGRES_USER=eli
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=database
    env_file:
      - .env
  database:
    image: postgres:9.6.8-alpine
    environment: # postgress should be getting these variables, not the variables set in the env file thats for localhost
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata
    ports:
      - 8002:5432
    env_file:
      - .env
  react_client:
      build:
        context: ./client
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      image: react_client
      working_dir: /home/node/app/client
      volumes:
        - ./:/home/node/app
      ports:
        - 8001:8001
      env_file:
        - ./client/.env
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Comment: Seems to me that this is not a Docker issue but PostgreSQL one. Look at the error you've posted `Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: role "eli" does not exist` if Docker weren't picking up your ENV variable why or how it would complain about an inexistent role?

Comment: Environment variables defined in the docker-compose file take precedence over those in the `env_file`. Remove them from the compose file.

Comment: I see how would i be able to use the variables defined in the environement section opposed to the .env file. I removed `env_file` and i still get the error `Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: role "eli" does not exist` This is a docker issue, because it works on my local host.

Comment: @randal don't remove the `env_file`, remove the `environment:` section from your compose file.

Comment: ok let me try it

Comment: i still get the sequelise connection error. u got a repo that uses react, express, and sequelize u can redirect me to ?

Comment: Did you create a database user with that name?

Comment: no, thats the database user of the localhost production, not docker. so when i npm start, and have postgress running on my localhost, it works. But i have not setup a postgress database user role on docker because im unsure how, and how to have docker know what variables to use.

Comment: wait im referencing this https://github.com/anthub-services/docker-for-node-api-and-client-boilerplates

and i think im missing the docker sequelize commands.

Comment: Hey @randal, am haing a question, how did you connect the Postgres container? did you use an already uploaded container, or you were referencing the database locally ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL/DR**

Try updating the docker-compose service database environment section as follows:

```
environment:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-password}
  POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-user}
  POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-db}
```

Also notice that if you would like to see how each bound variable ultimately evaluates in Compose you can run the following command to see the "effective" compose file:

**$ docker-compose config**

This command will print out what your compose file looks like with all variable substitution replaced with its evaluation.

---

See the [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) and the [Variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) sections in the documentation.

Pay close attention to this section:

> When you set the same environment variable in multiple files, here’s
>   the priority used by Compose to choose which value to use:
>
> ```
> 1. Compose file 
> 2. Shell environment variables 
> 3. Environment file Dockerfile
> 4. Variable is not defined
> ```
>
> In the example below, we set the same environment variable on an Environment file, and the Compose file:
>
> ```
> $ cat ./Docker/api/api.env
> NODE_ENV=test
>
> $ cat docker-compose.yml 
> version: '3' 
> services:
> api:
>   image: 'node:6-alpine'
>   env_file:
>     - ./Docker/api/api.env
>   environment:
>     - NODE_ENV=production
> ```
>
> When you run the container, the environment variable defined in the Compose file takes precedence.
>
> ```
> $ docker-compose exec api node
> process.env.NODE_ENV 'production'
> ```
>
> Having any ARG or ENV setting in a Dockerfile evaluates only if there is no Docker Compose entry for environment or env_file.
>
> > Specifics for NodeJS containers
> >
> > If you have a `package.json` entry for `script:start` like `NODE_ENV=test node server.js`, then this overrules any setting in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Can you kindly explain this `${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-password}` more, is this the env variable from the `.env` file, the syntax is a bit weird

Comment: See the answer to this SO question pertaining to the syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013589/328275

Comment: See also bash parameter substitution: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: Thank you, docker-compose config is super useful!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, any help is apreciated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78249196/unable-to-connect-to-postgres-database-from-net-api-each-on-a-docker-containe