# Stumped: this script does not work as expected?

Tags: bash, unix

I'm stumped when writing a simple script.

Essentially the $u variable is does not take u=$USER.  Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# > 0 ] ; then
    u=$1
else
    u=$USER
fi
echo $u
```

Comment: I think the `>` in `if [ $# > 0 ] ; then` is not doing what you think it is. Please refer to [Comparing numbers in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash).

Comment: Within single brackets `bash` interprets `>` as output redirection and creates a file named `0` in the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The fix

You have 2 equally viable options:

1. Use `-gt`

```sh
if [ $# -gt 0 ]
```

2. Use double brackets `[[` (Does a lexicographic comparison but will work for this case)

```sh
if [[ $# > 0 ]]
```

#### Why?

When you did `if [ $# > 0 ]`  the `>` was treated like an [output redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) command similar to `echo "foo" > file.txt`. You might notice you have created a file named `0` someplace after executing:

```sh
if [ $# > 0 ]
```

When deciding between using `[...]` or `[[...]]` many find the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-ba) is to use double brackets

#### Getting fancy

Now if what you'd really like to do is write a script that gives a default value to the `u` variable if none is provided by the first argument I would recommend using a neat bash [syntax trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013547/assigning-default-values-to-shell-variables-with-a-single-command-in-bash) for implementing default values

```sh
u=${1:-${USER}}
```

Comment: That's `u=${1:-$USER}` (note the `'-'` instead of `'='`)

Comment: Additionally the `>` with `[[...]]` isn't a numeric comparison, e.g. `"When used with [[, the < and > operators sort lexicographically using the current locale."` (~line 282 in man bash)  (the `-gt` is still proper) Rest looks good.

Comment: You're right that `[[ a > b ]]` is not doing what one might think it would do, but in this case `$#` will be some number `0,1,2...100,101...` and it will be compared to `0`. Using `[[ $# > 0 ]]` will work the way OP **wants it to** but perhaps not in the **way they might expect**.

Comment: Yes, you are safe for ASCII (and all LOCALEs I can think of), and you noted the sort, so people won't come away thinking it does something different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer using double brackets

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# > 0 ]] ; then
    u=$1
else
    u=${USER}
fi
echo $u
```

Not sure I fully understand why it failed with single brackets.

Comment: Single brackets are explained in `man test`: You need `-gt`,