# How can I override a bash variable at the time of executing it in console?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, parameter-expansion

I have a bash script that will print yesterdays date. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

YESTERDAY_DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d '1 day ago')
echo $YESTERDAY_DATE
```

> and I can run it like: `./script.sh`, output as follows:

```
2021-02-23
```

Now, I want to be able to override it at execution time so I went ahead and changed it to:

```
#!/bin/bash

: ${YESTERDAY_DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d '1 day ago')}
YESTERDAY_DATE_OVERRIDE=${$YESTERDAY_DATE:-(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d '1 day ago')}
echo $YESTERDAY_DATE
```

> and when I run it like: `YESTERDAY_DATE=2015-12-30 ./script.sh`, output as follows:

```
./script.sh: line 4: ${$YESTERDAY_DATE:-(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d '1 day ago')}: bad substitution
2015-12-30
```

**It does print the overridden date but with a bad substitution error. Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: Drop the `$` before `YESTERDAY_DATE:-`.

Comment: ... and replace `:-` with `:=$`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you wanna put that as an answer so I can mark it as resolved?

Comment: I propose to close the question with reference to [Assigning default values to shell variables with a single command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2013547/3776858)

Comment: More details: [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning default values to shell variables with a single command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013547/assigning-default-values-to-shell-variables-with-a-single-command-in-bash)

Comment: I agree that the duplicate is helpful (which is why I helped close the question as a duplicate).  However, the primary problem in the code shown is a missing `$` in `YESTERDAY_DATE_OVERRIDE=${$YESTERDAY_DATE:-(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d '1 day ago')}`, which should have a `$` before the open parenthesis: `YESTERDAY_DATE_OVERRIDE=${$YESTERDAY_DATE:-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d '1 day ago')}` so that the parenthesized expression is evaluated as a command substitution.