# What does "FORWARD_VAR_NAME" mean in a docker-compose file under a service's "ports" section?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the `docker-compose.yaml` file created by Laravel Sail is an entry under a service's `ports` section reading `FORWARD_REDIS_PORT`.
I understand the [short](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#short-syntax-3)  and [long](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#long-syntax-3)  syntax of a service's `ports` section.  But, have never seen a variable pre-pended with `FORWARD_`.  What does this syntax mean?  And how does it differ from using the [short](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#short-syntax-3) syntax for ports?

Example of Docker-Compose Ports short syntax

```yaml
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

Example of Docker-Compose from Laravel Sail

```yaml
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variable, that can be defined in multiple ways, some of them are in an `.env` file, in the shell running the `docker-compose` command or added when running the command, like

```bash
FORWARD_REDIS_PORT=1234 docker-compose up
```

The `:-6379` part is actually called [bash parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013589/2123530) and it defines a default to a variable if it was found undefined when used.
So, in your case, if your environment, shell, etc., does not define the variable `FORWARD_REDIS_PORT`, you will effectively end up mapping the port `6379` of your host to the port `6379` of your container.

This behaviour is described in the documentation page [*"Ways to set environment variables in Compose"*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#compose-file) and its chapter [*"Substitute from the shell"*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-from-the-shell).